# How to get a Part of the Directory path in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a BAT file in a directory

```
D:\dir1\dir2\getpath.bat
```

when i run the bat with the below code it prints

```
D:\dir1\dir2\
```

i want only the path `D:\dir1\`

The directory structure is not fixed , need the complete directory path other than the current directory in which BAT file resides.

```
@echo off
SET SUBDIR=%~dp0
ECHO %SUBDIR%
```

tried using delims in a for loop but it didnt help.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. What exactly are you trying to do? What specifies your "complete directory path"? Let's say you move your script to `F:\other\bins\own`, what should be your output? `F:\other\bins\ `, `F:\other\ ` or something else entirely?

Comment: @SvenS : i want the output as F:\other\bins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the parent directory of the directory your script resides in you want, then try this:

```
@echo off
SET batchdir=%~dp0
cd /D "%batchdir%.."
echo %CD%
cd "%batchdir%"
```

(untested, please comment if there are problems)

Note that this will, of course, change nothing if your batch resides in your drive root (as in `F:\`) ;) If you'd like a special output if that's the case, you should test `%CD%` against `%batchdir%` before the echo.

EDIT: Applied patch, see comment by @RichardA

Comment: Will this work when run from a different directory or a different drive? Would pushd/popd be simpler than saving off batchdir?

Comment: Oh, you're right, I'll edit in a patch. `%~dp0` is not the working directory but the directory the batch resides in ([source](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=54333.0)), so you need to cd into that dir first (if that's what is desired). I can't really say anything to pushd/popd.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET SUBDIR=%~dp0
call :parentfolder %SUBDIR:~0,-1% 
endlocal
goto :eof

:parentfolder
echo %~dp1
goto :eof
```

Comment: if `%~dp0=C:\dir1\dir2` setting `%SUBDIR:~0,-1%` will turn it into `C:\dir1\dir`. Given if the OP doesn't have directories with the same name in a single numbered sequence, this doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: @Mechaflash: Did you try this at your end? Well what you said isn't the final step. The value "C:\dir1\dir" is passed to another routine which does ECHO. It will work perfectly if you try running

Comment: I like this answer. It'd be good practice to bracket the code with setlocal/endlocal so that SUBDIR isn't available outside the batch file context.

Comment: @RichardA Thanks Richard. Edited to include localization.

Comment: @Arun, I hope you don't think I was being picky. Oh, the endlocal is one line too low, should be before the `goto :eof`.

Comment: @RichardA no problem at all! I was truly appreciating your accurate inputs. You are right again, the endlocal was at a place which would have never got executed! Thanks again for pointing the issue - especially when this would not have resulted in a runtime error in most cases. But you are absolutely right, putting it at a wrong place had the potential to invite troubles that would have been hard to debug. I have corrected it. Truly thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
SET MYDIR=%cd%
cd %MYDIR%\..
SET MYPARENTDIR=%cd%
cd %MYDIR%
```

Answer (score 1):

A single line of code does it :-)

If you want the trailing back slash, then

```
for %%A in ("%~dp0.") do @echo %%~dpA
```

If you don't want the trailing back slash, then

```
for %%A in ("%~dp0..") do @echo %%~fA
```

Comment: Why on earth would someone down vote this? It gives the correct answer, and is very efficient, both from the standpoint of amount of code, as well as performance.

Answer (score 0):

%~dp0 returns the full drive letter and path of the current batch file. This can be used in a FOR command to obtain portions of the path:

When run from `C:\dir1\dir2\dir3\batch.bat`

```
FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\") DO @ECHO %%~dpV
```

returns `C:\dir1\dir2\`

This can be extended to continue higher up the path:

```
FOR %%V IN ("%~dp0..\..\") DO @ECHO %%~dpV
```

returns `C:\dir1\`

[Source: Microsoft info on batch parameters](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score -1):

You almost had it right. Using %~dp0 grabs the Drive+Full path to your .bat so it will return the folder which your bat file is located in as well.

Since the active directly will be the directory your bat is run from, all you'll need to do is:

```
@echo off
CD ..
SET SUBDIR=%CD%
ECHO %SUBDIR%
```

If putting this in a bat script to verify, throw in a `PAUSE` on a newline to see your output.

Comment: Why will the active directory be the directory your bat is run from? What if he calls it the active directory is c:\ and he runs D:\dir1\dir2\getpath.bat? Wont the active directly by c:\?