# How to extract folder path from a string in a batch script

Tags: svn, batch-file, diff, xcopy

I have been working on building a packaging utility which basically gets all added/modified files between two SVN revisions, then copies them locally and zips them.So far, I have been able to successfully extract all changed files between two revisions.

To go further, I am using xcopy to recursively create folders at a certain directory.

Assuming that the following files have changed when I check two revisions using svn diff command

```
/temp1/temp2/temp3/temfile.txt
/temp1/temp21/temp31/tempfile.txt
/temp1/temp2/ (folder created)
/temp1/temp2/temp3 (folder created)
```

For XCopy to work, I am doing

```
xcopy local/svn/copy/path d:/{folderpath}
```

where folderpath needs to be extracted from the above changed list e.g.

```
xcopy "C:/LocalSVN/temp1/temp2/temp3/temfile.txt" "d:/temp1/temp2/temp3/"
```

I need to in my batch file, extract only the folder path and remove the file name.What is the best way to do it in a batch file?

Is there a different way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You should read the post 5 hours before yours: [How to get a Part of the Directory path in a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7527529/463115)

Comment: I am afraid, this does not solve my problem! The solution works with directories and relates to the path in which the bat file resides.If you read my problem carefully, It has to do with processing strings, which contain a directory path.

Comment: Perhaps you can find my answer to a [similar post here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527529/how-to-get-a-part-of-the-directory-path-in-a-batch-file/7532349#7532349

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nearly the same as in [How to get a Part of the Directory path in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7527529/463115)

The key is to use the %~dp functionality, and as this only works with parameters (not variables), you can use a FOR-Loop or a subroutine to move your variable into a parameter.

```
@echo off
set "testString=/temp1/temp2/temp3/temfile.txt"

call :GetPath returnVal "%testString%"
echo %returnVal%
exit /b

:GetPath
set "%1=%~dp2"
exit /b
```

Comment: This does'nt work as well..The output is C:\temp1\temp2\temp3\temfile.txt , where as the output I am looking for is just \temp1\temp2\temp3, without the drive letter...

Comment: As in `for /?` is explained, d=drive p=path, so you can use `set "%1=%~p2"` in your case

Comment: This doesn't work if the call is within a FOR loop. How can I solve this scenario?

Comment: @ScottChu I can't see any problem, but you should open a new question with your code

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
SET SUBDIR=%~dp0
call :parentfolder %SUBDIR:~0,-1% 
endlocal
goto :eof

:parentfolder
echo %~dp1
goto :eof
```